# How do I convert a list of strings into a URL query string in functional style?

Tags: functional-programming

This question is about functional programming, not about how to build URL query strings. The language I'm working in is Objective-C but that's also not especially relevant.

I have a starting data structure that's an array of strings. Each odd element is the parameter name, each even one is the value eg, [firstname, bob, lastname, smith, gender, male].

Is there an idiomatic FP approach to converting this list into a URL query string (eg. "firstname=bob&lastname=smith&gender=male")?

I'm thinking something along the lines of 'partition using a mod 2 predicate' to give me 2 lists of keys and values respectively, then zipWith a function that url escapes the keys and values and joins them with '='. That will give me a list of 'a=b' strings. Then I should be able to do a fold-left to insert the '&' symbols.

I think I may have just answered my own question! Sweet! Posting it anyway in case someone more familiar with FP idioms wants to comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more-or-less direct translation of your English into C#:

```
var list = new[]{"firstname", "bob", "lastname", "smith", "gender", "male"};

string.Join("&", 
            list.Where((k, i) => i % 2 == 0)
                .Zip(list.Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 1),
                    (k, v) => k + "=" + v));
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be more or less it, in Haskell using only standard prelude functions:

```
queryStr paramList  =  joinAmp $ map (uncurry joinEq) $ group2 paramList
  where joinEq x y  =  x ++ "=" ++ y

joinAmp  =  foldr1 (\x y -> x ++ "&" ++ y)

group2 []        =  []
group2 (x:y:xs)  =  (x, y) : group2 xs

qStr = queryStr ["firstname", "bob", "lastname", "smith", "gender", "male"]
```

Check whether your environment has a string joining function. E.g., in Python you can do `"&".join(lst)` for the `joinAmp` function, above. I've used a right-fold because of the way Haskell implements string concatenation.

Comment: I like this solution best due to the haskell awesomeness, but I have to accept the C# solution as being the closest translation.

Answer (score -1):

```
String o;    
for (i=0; i< -1 + size(strings); i=i+2) {

        if (i==0) {
            o += "?";
        } else {
            o += "&";
        };

        o+= strings[i]+"="+ strings[i+1];

    }
    print o;
```

Comment: This is a *non*-functional approach to the problem!

Comment: This is an imperative solution, not a functional one.